# Image of a Euclidean domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Considering Euclidean domains using a function $\varphi :E\setminus\lbrace 0\rbrace \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that

(i) $\varphi(a)\leq \varphi(ab)$ with $b\neq 0$.
(ii) for all $a,b\in E$, $b\neq 0$ existen $p,r \in E$ such that
$a=pb+r$ with $r=0$ or $\varphi(r)< \varphi(b)$.

and show that the condition (i) not necessary.

> But is necessary the condition $\varphi (E\backslash \lbrace 0\rbrace) \subset \mathbb{N}$ ?

My question arises because some
authors consider $\varphi :E\backslash \lbrace 0\rbrace \rightarrow \mathbb{W}$ where $\mathbb{W}$ is a well-ordered, but the latter definition increases the class of Euclidean domains? In any case I would like to have some Euclidean domain example with $\varphi :E\setminus\lbrace 0\rbrace \rightarrow \mathbb{W}$ and $\mathbb{W}\neq \mathbb{N}$. Thank you very much for the attention given.

Comment: Is "Euclidean dominos" a autocorrect slip? :)

Comment: Any field is an Euclidean domain with trivial norm. So you can have $\mathbb W=\{1\}$. And you will notice that it the structure of $\mathbb W$ beyond the ordering is immaterial; you can have it to be ${\bf N}\setminus \{2,463,1246\}$ for instance, by simply adjoining a bijection to $\varphi$.

Comment: In this article there is an example of such a set with $ W\neq N$ if someone had access to it, I would greatly appreciate a copy.

Comment: M. Nagata: On Euclid algorithm; in C.P. Ramanujan—A Tribute, Tata Inst. Fund. Res. Studies
in Math. 8, Springer, Berlin, 1978, 175–186.